# why capybara not working with bootstrap validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

i hit login button with empty form
Expectation: validation errors should appear and not allow to submit it
Normally it works as expected but via capybara ,form is getting submitted.

Want to test if error messages are appearing as expected.Not able to test since form is getting submitted.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to test JS driven behavior but are using the `rack_test` driver which doesn't support JS. See https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers